# List is taking too much space and EditText with buttons can't be viewed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-relativelayout

I want to have a `ListView`, followed by a `EdiText`, folowed by 2 buttons like:

```
ListView <NEWLINE>
EditText  <NEWLINE>
Button1 Button2 <NEWLINE>
```

I have the code and if the list is small everything goes well. However, if the list has many elements it will take all the space and I won't be able to see the `EditText` or the buttons.

I have trimmed it down to the part where the problem starts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/in"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_contacts"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" 
    />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_below="@id/in" />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/Convert"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/entry"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Convert" />
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/sendSMS"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Convert"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/Convert"
        android:text="Send" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the below code works for me and i hope it will work for you too...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              style="@style/MainLinearLayout">"

<TableLayout    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                style="@style/MainTableLayoutStyle">

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent" 

              >

    </ListView>

    <TableRow>
       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/entry"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
            android:layout_below="@id/in" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow >

    <Button  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/button1"
                 android:text="button1"
                 android:layout_gravity="left"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 />

    <Button  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/button1"
                 android:text="button2"
                 android:layout_gravity="right"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 />


    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sort of worked. The list views now apears above the buttons and other stuf i have before it(which i did not include in the question to make it short). i will investigate and update

Comment: If it's working for you then you should give me the UPVOTE....Everybody loves to get points...:)

Comment: I will. Let me just try it out,i still have zzzzzz answer pending. sry guys

Comment: Got it to work with the rest. But this way the editText in my code only ocupies 1 third of the row, even though there is nothing else in the same line. How can I fix this? FIXED: have to set the weigth of editText to 1. WORKS=)

Comment: well, when I try to select the listview to scroll, it now gives an error. wonder where it came from:S

Comment: Now when i'm typing in the edit. If i click in the listview the app will crash

Comment: I had tried it before and it didn't crash. I am not saying it's your code's fault. But when I add something to the list and try to click the list. it crashes( what was it even suppose to do? clicking an element in the list should do nothing so I don't know where to look)

Comment: have you override onListItemClick() in your program,if so,then post the code i'll check...

Comment: Thanks!:D but I havent,I only overrode the onresume. What the button does is it adds a SpannableStringBuilder to a Vector<SpannableStringBuilder> which is this List. But now, when I try to add another and then click the list it crashes, and i can't catch the error even though i surrounded the instruction inside the button's onClick with a try-catch

Comment: Well maybe you are right and my code is the problem... I TRIED to went back in the code and the same problem apears when I click a list element even though it wasnt supposed to do anything

Comment: Its really difficult to say anything about your crash of application without going through the code...

Comment: well if want i can send it to you. but seams like you would be going through to much trouble

Comment: Well the problem its not the layout so its solved. Thanks=) I alrdy voted

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your listview a fixed height.

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/in"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_contacts"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" 
    />
```

Another choice is to set the height programmatically in the code.  If you do this you need to do in the Activity's onWindowFocused() method.  You can then programmatically set it to say half your screen.

```
Private LinearLayout llfullscreen;//llfullscreen is the viewgroup 
                                  //that stretches the whole screen
Private ListView lv;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        llfullscreen = findViewById(R.id.bottomcontrol)
}
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            if(hasFocus && llfullscreen!=null){
        int layoutHeight = llfullscreen.getHeight(); 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = lv.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = lv/2; //Set to half the screens size
        this.lv.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.lv.invalidate();
             }
    }
```

Comment: How do I define llfullscreen? since it will be null when it reaches "llfullscreen.getHeight(); " right?
     And lv is my "in" list view correct?

Comment: No you define it in oncreate() which will occur before onWindowFocusChanged()

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but how do I define it in my oncreate function?

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere. Will you mark my answer correct if I show you?

Comment: Also your ListView needs to go inside your RelativeLayout in your .xml file.

Comment: in " findViewById(R.id.bottomcontrol)" what's the bottoncontrol? since I don't have that in the code I posted i cant get it to run:S

Comment: The bottomcontrol is the RelativeLayout in your xml file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 
it has no id, i gave him a id but when i did " llfullscreen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.The id);" it gave an error in runtime

Answer (score 0):

Because in ListView you use android:layout_weight="1.0" so, it took all space. you should add 1 layout to wrap your Text,Buttom etc. and add this android:layout_weight="2.0" or 3.0 (it's up to you) Try.

P.S. If it still not work For  Try change all android:layout_height="fill_parent" To android:layout_height="wrap_content"

```
    <ListView android:id="@+id/in"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_contacts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" 
        />
<Relativelaout
        android:id="@+id/bottomcontrol"
        android:layout_below="@id/in"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.0">
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
         />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/Convert"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/entry"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Convert" />
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/sendSMS"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Convert"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/Convert"
        android:text="Send" />
</RelativeLayout>
```